# JavaFX exe bundling for x86 windows systems

Tags: deployment, x86, java-7, 32-bit

usually I deploy my Java apps as a bundle which contains the JVM, so there's no need to install a JVM on the system.
Btw: This is no jnlp applet, this is a normal Swing Application.
I did this using ant's `fx:deploy`. This already works for 64bit systems.
My problem is, that I want to deploy this application to a 32bit system and don't get it to work.

Here's what I did:
I've set up a clean Windows 7 (32bit) instance and installed a 32bit JVM. Now i ran my ant script to build a bundled Java app and it built a App.exe. 
But when I tried to start this exe by double clicking, I get the following message box
[image: Failed to create JVM]
If I click OK, I get another message box
[image: Failed to launch JVM]
 After this the app is terminated.
I did not find anything searching the web relating to bundling for 32/64 bit systems.
So I would be very glad if someone can point me in the right direction.
Many thanks in advance!
Greetings, -chris-

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a known bug fixed for an upcoming JavaFX version (currently known as 2.2.40):

- [RT-25715 The Windows launcher generated by the packager fails to load msvcr100.dll on 32-bit OS](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092594)
- [RT-22610 .exe created by fx:deploy can't be executed due to missing msvcr100.dll](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8126704)

On the bug case, the user mentions a work-around:

> If I give a try to the workaround documented in RT-22610, which is to copy runtime\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll side to my application's launcher binary, it fixes it.

I think the bug is fixed in JDK 8, so another possible work-around is to download a [JDK 8 early access release](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) and use the packaging tools from there to package a Java 7 application (though I have never tried that and am not sure if it would work).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is still not working for me. The exe built by jdk8 just does nothing if started. Not even a error message.

Comment: The wourkaround works here, on 32 bit Win XP in a VirtualBox with a native bundle including java 7 jvm (upadate 45, I think).

Comment: The remaining question is: How can we get the installer to automatically put the dll in the right place?

Comment: Did anyone make progress on this? I believe there's a way to specify a custom InnoSetup script to run after app installation is complete, that could copy this file to the right place. If you modify fxbuild to specify "Verbose" mode, you'll see instructions about how to customise the installation this way.

Comment: got fixed in jdk8u40 and  jdk7u55

Answer (score 2):

Just a small modification to @jewelsea's Fix:

copying msvcr100.dll into the app/ folder instead putting it right next to the exe also works, and at least it is somewhat hidden away then.

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating an MSI you can hack the WXS file used by WIX to automatically copy msvcr100.dll into the app folder. Making FX Deploy verbose will tell you where it's putting the temporary WXS file you can copy and modify and use to override the WXS like you would the program icon for example.